# How does muslim creationist explain our malfunctioning Vitamin C encoder in our genes?

Tags: creation, evolution

Both creationists and evolutionist agree that there is indeed an easy way to differentiate evolution and design. When something is designed, vestigial remains do not exist. We do not have gas cars with remnant of broken coal tanks, for example.

Yet we do have genes that can create vitamin C. The genes are broken due to some mutation turning it off. The broken genes and places where it's broken are similar with the places where similar genes are found on other primates, like orang utan, gorilla, and chimps.

All those are exactly like predicted by evolution theory long before the facts are known.

So what's a Muslim creationist's explanation of this?

Comment: please note Islamic creationism and Christian creationism are completely different.

Answer (score 5):

Living things were created from water:

> Have those who disbelieved not considered that the heavens and the earth were a joined entity, and We separated them and made from water every living thing? Then will they not believe? (Al-'Anbiya' 21:30)
>
> Allah has created every [living] creature from water. And of them are those that move on  their bellies, and of them are those that walk on two legs, and of them are those that walk on four. Allah creates what He wills. Indeed, Allah is over all things competent. (An-Nur 24:45)

Adam was created from clay:

> And We did certainly create man out of clay from an altered black mud. (Al-Hijr 15:26)
>
> That is the Knower of the unseen and the witnessed, the Exalted in Might, the Merciful, Who perfected everything which He created and began the creation of man from clay. (As-Sajdah 32:6-7)

The majority of the Quran - the commandments, are to be taken literally. The rest are not specific and more like storytelling. These vague ones are not the foundation of the Book.

> It is He who has sent down to you, [O Muhammad], the Book; in it are verses [that are] precise - they are the foundation of the Book - and others unspecific. ('Ali-Imran 3:7)

So here, Allah does not give the fine details of **how** Allah and the angels created man. They could have been evolved out of something. They could have been literally clay and formed into a figure of a man. Or Adam might have been a clay mould mixed with the essence (whatever that means) of another living creature.

I don't think anyone can dispute that living things are mostly water, but Muslim theologists will argue about what creation from clay really means.

There's nothing in the Quran actually disagreeing with evolution. Maybe disagreement that humans evolved from primates. But Vitamin C or whatever is still insufficient evidence. Maybe Allah created apes in the same way as humans, which is why they have similar genes. Maybe apes were an early prototype of humans made with the wrong kind of clay.

Comment: Hmmm... This actually makes some sense. Good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this example, the Jinn (the unseen beings) can teleport around and they aren't subject to physical constraints like us. However, the spirit is comparable to the Jinn in this regard, and this is a requirement because Allah tells us that we were created in the best form, so of course this is not surprising at all. A known example is Prophet Zecharias bypassing physical constraints and entering the tree, which shows us that with Allah's permission one can use these powers inside us. But some of our features are disabled for some reasons Allah's wisdom requires.

About the similarity of humans and animals, see this answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/79672